# how would one limit ssh tunnel access?

Tags: linux, ssh, vps

I have a SSH service on a VPS (linux if it makes any difference) and i recently bought and one of the uses for it is to make a secure SOCKS proxy tunnel. My issue is it allows all traffic on any port to forward through. Is there a way on the server end I can limit this to certain ports perhaps by using iptables?

Would i need to make an OUTPUT or FORWARD rule? If so how can I tell the rule that it only applies to ssh traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PermitOpen` option to sshd on the server side looks like it will do what you want. You can also combine this with the `Match User` option to limit by user. For example:

```
Match User alice
PermitOpen www.example.com:80 server2.example.com:443
```

Comment: See also permitopen="host:port" in authorized_keys if using key-based authentication.